# XML Schema How to Restrict Attribute by Enumeration

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XML Tag

```
<price currency="euros">20000.00</price>
```

How do I restrict the currency attribute to one the following:

- euros
- pounds
- dollars

AND the price to a double?

I just get an error when I try to a type on both, here's what I've got so far:

```
<xs:element name="price">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="currency">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="pounds" />
                    <xs:enumeration value="euros" />
                    <xs:enumeration value="dollars" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: If you do this you need to remove type="xs:string" from the <xs:attribute> element as well. You can't give the type when simpleType or complexType is present.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The numerical value seems to be missing from your price definition.
Try the following:

```
<xs:simpleType name="curr">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="pounds" />
    <xs:enumeration value="euros" />
    <xs:enumeration value="dollars" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>



<xs:element name="price">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
              <xs:attribute name="currency" type="curr"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: As answered by @kjhughes, the `<xs:extension` can't directly be a child of `<xs:complexType` but instead must also be contained by a `<xs:complexContent` or `<xs:simpleContent`.

Answer (score 28):

### New answer to old question

*None of the existing answers to this old question address the **real problem.***

***The real problem*** was that `xs:complexType` cannot directly have a `xs:extension` as a child in XSD.  The fix is to use `xs:simpleContent` first.  Details follow...

---

Your XML,

```
<price currency="euros">20000.00</price>
```

will be valid against *either* of the following corrected XSDs:

### Locally defined attribute type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="price">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
          <xs:attribute name="currency">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="pounds" />
                <xs:enumeration value="euros" />
                <xs:enumeration value="dollars" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### Globally defined attribute type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="currencyType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="pounds" />
      <xs:enumeration value="euros" />
      <xs:enumeration value="dollars" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="price">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
          <xs:attribute name="currency" type="currencyType"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### Notes

- As [commented by @Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925706/xml-schema-how-to-restrict-attribute-by-enumeration#comment50320548_8925706), these do change the content type of
  `price` from `xs:string` to `xs:decimal`, but this is not strictly
  necessary and was not the real problem.
- As [answered by @user998692](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8926259/290085), you could separate out the
  definition of currency, and you could change to `xs:decimal`, but
  this too was not the real problem.

**The real problem** was that `xs:complexType` cannot directly have a `xs:extension` as a child in XSD; `xs:simpleContent` is needed first.

A related matter (that wasn't asked but may have confused other answers):

***How could `price` be restricted given that it has an attribute?***

In this case, a separate, global definition of `priceType` would be needed; it is not possible to do this with only local type definitions.

### How to restrict element content when element has attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="priceType">  
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">  
      <xs:minInclusive value="0.00"/>  
      <xs:maxInclusive value="99999.99"/>  
    </xs:restriction>  
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="price">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="priceType">
          <xs:attribute name="currency">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="pounds" />
                <xs:enumeration value="euros" />
                <xs:enumeration value="dollars" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 9):

you need to create a type and make the attribute of that type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="curr">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="pounds" />
    <xs:enumeration value="euros" />
    <xs:enumeration value="dollars" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

then:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="currency" type="curr"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Hello, Sadly this doesn't allow me to restrict the Price type to "double" AND the restriction enumeration on the "currency" attribute at the same time