# XSD : restrict many different attributes that take the same values

Tags: attributes, xsd, restrict

I want to do this:
[XML Schema How to Restrict Attribute by Enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925706/xml-schema-how-to-restrict-attribute-by-enumeration)

...but I have MANY different attributes that take the exact same values. This makes my XSD very complex.
Can I define the restriction once and then reference it on each attribute somehow ???

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have many different attributes that take on the **exact same values**, simply reuse the attribute type definitions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">

  <xs:simpleType name="colorType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="red" />
      <xs:enumeration value="green" />
      <xs:enumeration value="blue" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="RoomColors">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="wall" type="colorType"/>
      <xs:attribute name="carpet" type="colorType"/>
      <xs:attribute name="ceiling" type="colorType"/>
      <xs:attribute name="funiture" type="colorType"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>  

</xs:schema>
```

It's when the values are not the exact same that there's more creativity involved.  See [Extend enumerated lists in XML schema](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-extenum/).