# How can I restrict the number of elements with a given attribute value using XSD?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have an XML schema defining "rules" for a process. Each "rule-set" applies to a given list of "resources", which are defined like this:

```
<rule_sets>
  <rule_set name="Set 1" active="true">
    <resources>
      <resource>Resource 1</resource>
      <resource>Resource 2</resource>
    </resources>
    <rule ... />
    <rule ... />
  </rule_set>
  <rule_set name="Set 2" active="false">
    <resources>
      <resource>Resource 2</resource>
      <resource>Resource 3</resource>
    </resources>
    <rule ... />
    <rule ... />
  </rule_set>
```

I would like to add a restriction to my XSD that allows each resource to be assigned to only one "active" rule-set; i.e. a 'rule_set[@active="true"]'. (Each resource can be assigned to any number of inactive rule-sets.)

Is this possible in XSD?

So far I've just added a key to the "rule_sets" element (which is the parent of "rule_set") like this:

```
<xs:key name="rule_set_resource_active_key">
    <xs:selector xpath="rule_set" />
    <xs:field xpath="resources/resource" />
    <xs:field xpath="@active" />
</xs:key>
```

But this restricts me to each resource being on a maximum of one active rule-set and one inactive rule-set, which isn't really what I want. Is it possible to extend this to cover my requirement? Or could I restructure my document to achieve this?

Comment: Could you have the `rule_set` be a dependent element of `resource`, then set the `max_occurs` to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define two types of rulesets in XSD (if thats a possibility in your case) which have everything else same (use xs:group for defining at one place and reuse in both ruleSet definitions) but attribute active has different restrictions (refer [XML Schema How to Restrict Attribute by Enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925706/xml-schema-how-to-restrict-attribute-by-enumeration) for restricting attribute values in XSD). Then you can have two elements inside rule_sets one with maxoccurs bounded to 1 and the other unbounded.