# Add constraint on a field on deserializeion

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

in the xsd schema I have defined an attribute Id as

```
<xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" use="required"/>
```

However, the validation of xml towards the xsd schema passes even if ID is set to a value greater then `UInt32.MaxValue`.

My deserialization code looks as follows:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |    XmlSchemaValidationFlags.AllowXmlAttributes;
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.Schemas.Add(_schemaNs, _schemaFileName);

var tReader = XmlReader.Create(filename, settings);
try
{
      var obj = ser.Deserialize(tReader) as MyClass;
}
catch(Excetion e)
{/*Process Validation exception.*/}
```

where the corresponding variables are defined above.

In the definition of `MyClass` I have:

```
    private uint idField;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public uint ID
    {

        get
        {               
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
```

Now, I'd like the XmlSerializer to throw an exception if the value of ID is set to a too big number. The first idea, which came to my mind is to set the type of ID field in `MyClass` to `string` and perform validation by myself. However it seems that there is a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to encode the logic for filtering undesired values not into the deserialization, but into the setter itself, which can be done as follows.

```
private uint idField;
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public uint ID
{
    get
    {               
        return this.idField;
    }
    set
    {
        int SOME_BOUND = 10000;
        if (value > SOME_BOUND)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException();
        }
        this.idField = value;
    }
}
```

The class `ApplicationException` is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The [ArgumentOurOfBoundsException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might also be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can specify it in the XSD Schema this way:

```
<xs:attribute name="ID" use="required">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="4294967295"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

The following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925706/xml-schema-how-to-restrict-attribute-by-enumeration) might be helpful too.