# XML Schema: converting simpletype to anonymous type

Tags: xml, xsd, xslt-1.0, xsd-validation, xsd-1.0

I have a schema that I would like to convert the simpleType into anonymous simpleType. Original schema is as below, I did several attempts such as:

> Removing base="xxx";
>
> Adding the simpleType after the extension;
>
> Etc...

But ended up with invalid schema.

**Questions**:

1. How to convert the input into a valid anonymous simpleType schema without losing information?
2. Further more, is there xslt to do this automatically with dynamic input on the element name, type name etc?

Thanks in advance,

**Input Schema**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="test" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="test" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="elem1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="simpleType1">
                <xs:attribute name="att1" type="simpleType2" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="simpleType1">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:fractionDigits value="5"/>
        <xs:totalDigits value="18"/>
        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="simpleType2">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{3,3}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

My attempted result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="test" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="test" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="elem1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        <xs:fractionDigits value="5"/>
                        <xs:totalDigits value="18"/>
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
                <xs:attribute name="att1" use="required"/>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{3,3}"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Validation shows that this is an invalid schema with errors such as:

> Attribute 'base' is required in element .
>
> Element  is not allowed under element .
>
> Attribute 'name' is required in element .

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in XSD to use purely anonymous, local definitions when declaring an element to have both restricted content and an attribute.

You can, of course, use a local definition for the type of the attribute (`att1`) alone, but you cannot for the type (`simpleType1`) of the restricted simple content of the element (`elem1`) if you need to also declare `att1` on `elem1`.

**See also:** [***How to restrict element content when element has attribute***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33303107/290085)

Comment: Yes, in fact, I've managed to use the local defined type on attribute, but not able to do it with the 'extension base' on simpleType1...